# How to split BLE FTMS Indoor Bike Data into two chunks to match max of 20bytes per chunk

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, arduino-esp32

this is my first approach coding a BLE FTMS service for an ESP32 board. To be honest I'm not really experienced and this is my first C++ application. I managed to create a FTMS service and send data to a training app e.g. KinoMap or similar. My problem is I only managed to send data which doesn't exceed the 20bytes limit.

I read in the specs that I have to split it into 2 chunks and add a "more data bit" to the first chunk to be able to send more then 20bytes and to make sure the client knows that a second chunk of data is available. This is where I'm struggling.

I'm probably not experienced enough to see what is wrong and the more I read about the BLE FTMS specs my confusion raises ;) I found no description how to add this "more data bit" and how it would look like... I tried using 0x01 but I don't know if this is the right way to add it.

This way it is working with the max of 20bytes:

```
...
byte features[] = {0x07,0x52,0x00,0x00};

void transmitFTMS(double rpm, double avgRpm, double cadence, double avgCadence, double kph, double avgKph, double power, double avgPower, 
                  double runningDistance, double runningCalories, unsigned long elapsedTime)
{
    uint16_t transmittedKph        = (uint16_t) (kph * 100);         //(0.01 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedTime       = (uint16_t) (elapsedTime / 1000);//(1.0 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedAvgKph     = (uint16_t) (avgKph * 100);      //(0.01 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedRpm        = (uint16_t) (rpm * 2);           //(0.5 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedAvgRpm     = (uint16_t) (avgRpm * 2);         //(0.1 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedCadence    = (uint16_t) (cadence * 2);
    uint16_t transmittedAvgCadence = (uint16_t) (avgCadence * 2);
    uint16_t transmittedPower      = (uint16_t) (power * 2);      //(1.0 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedAvgPower   = (uint16_t) (avgPower * 2);        //(1.0 resolution)
    uint32_t transmittedDistance   = (uint32_t) (runningDistance * 1000);// runningDistance in km, need m 
    uint16_t transmittedTotalCal   = (uint16_t) (runningCalories * 10);                   //(1.0 resolution)
    uint16_t transmittedCalHr      = (uint16_t) (runningCalories * 60 * 60 / elapsedTime);//(1.0 resolution) 
    uint8_t transmittedCalMin      = (uint8_t)  (runningCalories * 60 / elapsedTime);     //(1.0 resolution)
    
    bool disconnecting = !deviceConnected && oldDeviceConnected;
    bool connecting = deviceConnected && !oldDeviceConnected;
    
    byte bikeData[20]={0x56,0x09,
                    (uint8_t)transmittedKph,        (uint8_t)(transmittedKph >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedAvgKph,     (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgKph >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedCadence,    (uint8_t)(transmittedCadence >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedDistance,   (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 16),        
                    (uint8_t)transmittedPower,      (uint8_t)(transmittedPower >> 8),                   
                    (uint8_t)transmittedTotalCal,   (uint8_t)(transmittedTotalCal >> 8),                    
                    (uint8_t)transmittedCalHr,      (uint8_t)(transmittedCalHr >> 8),                    
                    transmittedCalMin,
                    (uint8_t)transmittedTime,      (uint8_t)(transmittedTime >> 8)
      };
    if (deviceConnected)
    {
        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t *)&bikeData, 20);
        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->notify();
    }
...
```

I tried to change this as follows to submit more then 20bytes:

```
...
    byte bikeData1[20]={0x56,0x09,
                    (uint8_t)transmittedKph,        (uint8_t)(transmittedKph >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedAvgKph,     (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgKph >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedCadence,    (uint8_t)(transmittedCadence >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedRpm,        (uint8_t)(transmittedRpm >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedAvgRpm,     (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgRpm >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedAvgCadence, (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgCadence >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedDistance,   (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 16),        
                    (uint8_t)transmittedPower,      (uint8_t)(transmittedPower >> 8),
                    0x01
    };
    byte bikeData2[9]={
                    (uint8_t)transmittedAvgPower,   (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgPower >> 8),
                    (uint8_t)transmittedTotalCal,   (uint8_t)(transmittedTotalCal >> 8),                    
                    (uint8_t)transmittedCalHr,      (uint8_t)(transmittedCalHr >> 8),                    
                    transmittedCalMin,
                    (uint8_t)transmittedTime,      (uint8_t)(transmittedTime >> 8)
      };
    if (deviceConnected)
    {
        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t *)&bikeData1, 20);
        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->notify();

        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->setValue((uint8_t *)&bikeData2, 9);
        indoorBikeDataCharacteristic->notify();
    }
...
```

But then the client application isn't able to deal with the data provided and I don't know the reason why it fails.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction, because I'm working on this for the last 3 weeks without having any luck. I also tried to change the order of the submitted data or which data is submitted in each chunk but all I have tried doesn't get it to work like expected.

I don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [FTMS spec](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/fitness-machine-service-1-0/), Indoor Bike Data is defined in 4.9. In the flags field, you're passing 0x56, 0x09, which in little-endian format is:

```
100101010110
```

According to 4.9.1.1 Flags Field, this indicates you are sending:

- Average Speed
- Instantaneous Cadence
- Total Distance
- Instantaneous Power
- Expended Energy
- Elapsed Time

Your code sends:

```
// Instantaneous Speed (because More Data == 0)
(uint8_t)transmittedKph,        (uint8_t)(transmittedKph >> 8),

// Average Speed
(uint8_t)transmittedAvgKph,     (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgKph >> 8),

// Instantaneous Cadence
(uint8_t)transmittedCadence,    (uint8_t)(transmittedCadence >> 8),

// Total Distance
(uint8_t)transmittedDistance,   (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 8), (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 16),

// Instantaneous Power
(uint8_t)transmittedPower,      (uint8_t)(transmittedPower >> 8),                   

// Expended Energy (Total Energy, Energy per Hour, Energy per Minute)
(uint8_t)transmittedTotalCal,   (uint8_t)(transmittedTotalCal >> 8),                    
(uint8_t)transmittedCalHr,      (uint8_t)(transmittedCalHr >> 8),                    
transmittedCalMin,

// Elapsed Time
(uint8_t)transmittedTime,      (uint8_t)(transmittedTime >> 8)
```

So far, so good. You send what you say you send.

Then in your second batch, you seem to add a bunch of fields, but you don't update your flags, so I'm not quite certain what they all mean. These in particular, the `Rpm` fields look like they're just cadence. So I'm not sure what you mean them to be, but if you want to include Average Cadence, you need to turn on its bit. But then elapsed time won't fit, so you need to remove it.

That would be something like this. (Removing the Rpm fields because I don't know what they are.)

```
// 0x150E; adds Avg Cadence, removes elapsed time
// 0001 0101 1110
byte bikeData[]={0x0E,0x15,
                (uint8_t)transmittedKph,        (uint8_t)(transmittedKph >> 8),
                (uint8_t)transmittedAvgKph,     (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgKph >> 8),
                (uint8_t)transmittedCadence,    (uint8_t)(transmittedCadence >> 8),

                // Add Average Cadence
                (uint8_t)transmittedAvgCadence, (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgCadence >> 8),

                (uint8_t)transmittedDistance,   (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 8), (uint8_t)(transmittedDistance >> 16),        
                (uint8_t)transmittedPower,      (uint8_t)(transmittedPower >> 8),                   
                (uint8_t)transmittedTotalCal,   (uint8_t)(transmittedTotalCal >> 8),                    
                (uint8_t)transmittedCalHr,      (uint8_t)(transmittedCalHr >> 8),                    
                transmittedCalMin    
  };
```

Now you need to send "More Data." That means setting bit 0 in the flags, and **not** sending Instantaneous Speed.

```
// Flags: 0x4001, 0100 0000 0000 0001
byte bikeData2[]={0x01, 0x40
                (uint8_t)transmittedAvgPower,   (uint8_t)(transmittedAvgPower >> 8),
                (uint8_t)transmittedTime,      (uint8_t)(transmittedTime >> 8)
};
```

That's probably close. The key point is that your flags must describe what is in the packet, packets can't go over 20 bytes, and if you want to send a second packet that doesn't include Instantaneous Speed, set bit 0 ("More Data"). See section 4.9.1.1.

Note also that if you're going to send more fields, you need to update your `features` value to include them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes it easier for me to understand instead of only reading the ftms specs... maybe I should declare the flags first and add them afterwards for my readability ;)